# apache 2.4 SSL Cross Browser (work only in chrome)

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl, cross-browser

i want work my vhost in ssl, before today never it was a problem, but now i can not understand where is the problem.
in chrome all work fine, but with Firefox i have this messagge error

FIREFOX

**Codice di errore: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG**

IE 11

**La causa potrebbe essere che il sito utilizza impostazioni di sicurezza TLS obsolete o non sicure. In tal caso, provare a contattare il proprietario del sito Web**

and nothig other.

CHROME

**work!!**

this is my configuration vhost myhost.ssl.localhost

```
Define myhost myhost.ssl
Define hostextension localhost
Define DocumentRoot ${xampproot}/htdocs/test
Define certName ${myhost}.${hostextension}

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin test@test.localhost
    ServerName  ${myhost}.${hostextension}
    ServerAlias www.${myhost}.${hostextension} 

    DocumentRoot ${DocumentRoot}

    DirectoryIndex index.localhost.html index.php index.html index.htm
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/${certName}.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.key/${certName}.key"
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all      
        Require all granted         
    </Directory>

    # Ricordarsi di creare la directory
    ErrorLog  ${xampproot}/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}.error.log
    CustomLog ${xampproot}/logs/${myhost}.${hostextension}.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

after many and many attempt i can not what do now!

my step to create certificate

- openssl genrsa -aes256 -out myhost.ssl.localhost.key 2048
- openssl rsa -in myhost.ssl.localhost.key -out myhost.ssl.localhost.key
- openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -key myhost.ssl.localhost.key -out myhost.ssl.localhost.crt -days 36500 -config C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf
- copy files in correct folder path
- add set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\xampp\apache\conf\openssl.cnf

if i use 443 in address bar (http://myhost.ssl.localhost:443)

- **chrome** Bad Request 400
- **FF** Access Denied 403
- **IE11** Access Denied 403

Comment: Firefox does say record too long.  You built your certificate for 36500 days, that is 100 years right?  That is way to big.  And if any browser is 32bits (or uses a 32bits library for certificate validation), it cannot calculate dates after 2038 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).  Try with a more reasonable validity interval.

Comment: thanks, but i have used 700 days but nothing change

Comment: I did see this: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1222739 (TLS version) and this https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1224254 (Avast/AVG)

Comment: I had already set security.tls.version.max = 3, but not work. I have tried to turn off the  antivirus but nothing. for now nothing change my situation :(

Comment: If your site is available on Internet, try it through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/  If might point out something that could help.  Other than that, Firefox might publish their requirements for the version you have?

Comment: no, it's a localhost vhost :*(